# How to enumerate all possible keys that exist on a smartcard that is present in a reader with just UWP APIs?

Tags: c#, windows, api, uwp, smartcard

Here are the constraints for my question: How to enumerate all possible keys that exist on a smartcard that is present in a reader with UWP APIs?

1. Use just Universal Windows Program (UWP) APIs

I do have a C++ approach using NCryptOpenStorageProvider(MS_SMART_CARD_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER) and NCryptEnumKeys https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptenumkeys

2. I want to exclude keys that belong to a smartcard that is not physically present in a reader.

   Generally approaches that iterate through certificates in Cert stores have failed for me because  Windows pops up a dialog asking for a card to be inserted which is no longer available.  Maybe there is a way to exclude certificates like that, but I don't know the way.

Consequently it seems that an approach of iterating the keys through a provider makes more sense.

oldnewthing (who deserves thanks for helpful posts through the years) has a https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/SmartCard but it does not show this exact functionality.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/smart-cards explains how UWP can interact with smartcards, including APDU transfer, but does not explain how to iterate the asymmetric keys at a high level.

Thanks for advice in advance...

p.s.  here is the type of code that looks at the Cert Store, and gets a key.

```
            X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certs = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
            int n = certs.Count;
            msg += " has " + n.ToString() + " keys: ";

            foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certs)
            {
                if (!cert.HasPrivateKey) continue;

                RSACng rsaCng = (RSACng)cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
                if (null == rsaCng) continue;
                if (rsaCng.Key.Provider != CngProvider.MicrosoftSmartCardKeyStorageProvider) continue;
                msg += rsaCng.Key.KeyName + ", ";
            }
```

but I don't know how to restrict it to just keys that are currently present.

Comment: What type smartcard you have used, visual smart card or  physical smart card?

Comment: I used a physical smartcard, not virtual.

Comment: It looks only you mentioned  NCryptOpenStorageProvider  api could access the public key and derive from document  it could work for UWP platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the readers using SCard* functions, then set the `pszScope` argument of the `NCryptEnumKeys()` call to `L"\\\\.\\<ReaderName>\\"`.

Caution: this parameter is documented as "unused; set to NULL" in MSDN!

See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e99d3980-ae4f-4632-8dad-565e098dc6dd/how-to-enumerate-keys-on-all-connected-smart-cards-using-cng